# API Level 26: Sticky background Service

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Since Android O does not allow background services to be started without notifying the user, I did like to choose a different approach to run a new Thread in the background using the Firebase Jobdispatcher, see: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android

Before building for API 26, I used to start a new thread in a Service. Which is a **STICKY** service, and will restart when the user closes the app from recents (When slide to remove the app from the running apps).

See my original code before API 26 below.

```
public class NotificationService extends Service {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // this will start the thread
    ApplicationLoader.postInitApplication();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

In API 26, there came some restrictions:

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html#back-all

So the above method does not work anymore. But I still want my thread to run, even when the user closes the application from the recent apps. And I found a workaround, but it feels very bad for me.

```
FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher
                (new GooglePlayDriver(applicationContext));

Job notificationJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
          .setService(NotificationService.class)
          .setTag("backgroundJob-" + System.currentTimeMillis())
          .setRecurring(true)
          .setLifetime(Lifetime.UNTIL_NEXT_BOOT)
          .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(50, 60))
          .setReplaceCurrent(false)
          .build();
dispatcher.mustSchedule(notificationJob);
```

The service:

```
public class NotificationService extends JobService {

@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters job) {
    // this will check if the thread is started, if not it will start the thread
    ApplicationLoader.initNotificationThread();
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters job) {
    return false;
}
```

Now I found a workaround, this job checks each 50/60 seconds if my thread is running already, and if not it will start a thread. This keeps working, even if the user removes the app from the recent apps.

However, this solution feels uncomfortable. I am scheduling an intensive check, every minute, while it might be even unnecessary to do so.

Is there a better way to solve this? Is there some call I can do, like an `onDestroy()` call somewhere and then start a new job?

Comment: Have you found an answer or rolled back to API 25? I am trying to listen to ACTION_SCREEN_OFF/ACTION_SCREEN_ON broadcasts and waking process up every minute indeed sounds like overkill.

Comment: I implemented a foreground service with a notification with the instruction on how to hide it